# SQL GROUP BY, ORDER BY query returns a syntax error

Tags: sql, node.js

The following SQL code is not passing through to my backend code correctly.

This SQL code works in Postico just fine, however when it is called in the backend it does not work, providing the resultes pasted in from my terminal.

```
db.any(
  "SELECT week_num, COUNT(id) 
   FROM verylost 
   GROUP BY week_num  
   ORDER BY week_num ASC;")

Unhandled rejection error: syntax error at or near "ORDER BY week_num"
    at Connection.parseE (/Users/brentnewman/DC/final_project/classroom_emotion/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/brentnewman/DC/final_project/classroom_emotion/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:379:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/brentnewman/DC/final_project/classroom_emotion/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17)
```

Comment: I'd try to remove trailing `;`

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said : the problem is very likely to be the semicolon.

An SQL statement on its own does not (that is, not ever) need to be terminated by a statement terminator.

The need for statement terminators arose only when it became possible to write entire scripts and/or procedures in SQL.  So if and when you are writing ***entire procedures*** in SQL, then you will have to use semicolons to terminate statements (and the reason is that only then can the ***parser*** do its job of discerning one statement from another).  If and when you are merely issuing individual statements for execution, then there is no "discerning one statement from another", and terminating semicolons are superfluous, and most statement handlers in such contexts will actually fail if you do use them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I removed the semicolon and still get the same issue. Any other thoughts? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing trailing semicolon `;`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I removed the semicolon and still get the same issue. Any other thoughts? I appreciate it.